# Android Market - different download per sdk version

Tags: android

I have an app that is very stable with a min sdk of 9. However, a lot of the new additions I'm going to start adding are really only in version 11+ and I am wanting to just change the min sdk of my app to 11.

If I change the min sdk to 11, will all the people who currently have my app installed and sdk version 9 still have the app installed for them, but will just never see an update anymore since the min version is higher than their own?

Also, Since the new min is 11, will that also mean that no one with an sdk version lower than 11 will be able to download the app anymore since it wont appear in the market for them?

Comment: In my personal opinion all dependes by the changes..
If you change something like use fragment, new controls like pagination and drawer etc...with the support package you can mantain all the compatibility with the API level 9.
I think that you must take a look to this link: http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html

Try with this support package...maybe all your new implementation can be compatible with the older versions.

Comment: Take note, I do know that a lot of my new stuff could be done in older versions, as I have been. I'm wanting to know how the market works exactly before I decide what I want to do going forward.

Comment: In this case the answer for your question is: yes no one with the api level 9 can download it. But, take a look to this dashboard:
http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards
In this particular case of api level there are no problems...1.6% is a very small number of users..

Comment: Did this ever get answered?  I am also wanting to know what happens to EXISTING users if I change the min-sdk level of the app to a higher number.  If they just get orphaned, that's fine.